# Angular.min.js loading Failure

Tags: javascript, java, html, angularjs

I'm loading an external HTML template into my **JSP** page present in application context. The HTML is getting loaded on page loading ,But I have some angular controllers present in that html, those controllers are not working.
`angular.min.js` itself is not loading.

Html Template :-

```html
<html>

<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.6.4/angular.min.js"></script>
  <!--<script type="text/javascript" src=""+window.parent.x+"/js/angular.min.js"></script>-->
  <script type="text/javascript">
    var context = window.parent.x;
    var url = '' + context + '/dashboard.do?method=getdashboarddetails';
    getdashboarddata();
    var Obj1;

    function getdashboarddata() {
      var request;
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        request = new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        request = new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP');
      }
      try {
        request.onreadystatechange = getInfo;
        request.open("POST", url, false);
        request.send();
      } catch (e) {
        alert('Unable to connect to server');
      }

      function getInfo() {
        if (request.readyState === 4) {
          if (request.status === 200) {
            var val = eval("(" + request.responseText + ")");
            Obj1 = JSON.stringify(val);
          }
        }
      }
    }
  </script>
  <script>
    //Angular JS
    var helloAjaxApp = angular.module("myApp", []);
    helloAjaxApp.controller('mytime', function($scope, $interval) {
      $scope.theTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
      $interval(function() {
        $scope.theTime = new Date().toLocaleTimeString();
      }, 1000);
    });
    helloAjaxApp.controller("myCtrl", ['$scope', function($scope) {
      // $scope.sendGet = function() {

      //      $http({
      //          url :url,
      //          method : "POST"
      //        }).then(function(response) {
      alert(Obj1 + ' Angular');
      $scope.dashboard = Obj1;
      //     });
      //    };
    }]);
  </script>
</head>

<body>

  <div align="center">
    <font size="10" COLOR="#254117"><b>Customer Information Authorization</b></font>
  </div>
  <div ng-app="myApp">
    <div ng-controller="mytime">
      <h3 align="right">{{theTime}}</h3>
    </div>
    <div align="left" ng-controller="myCtrl">
      <table style="border-radius: 25px; background: #dfffff; border-collapse: collapse; margin: 15px; width:45%; height:40%; font-size:20px;">
        <tr style="color:white;background-color:#81A594;">
          <td>Quick Status</td>
          <td align="right">
            <!--  <button  ng-click="sendGet()">
   <img src="images/refresh.jpg" alt="Refresh" height="22" width="22">
   </button> -->
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td style=" text-align: left; padding: 8px;">
            <table style="background-color: white; width:100%;">
              <th style=" background-color: #81A594;color: white;">Branch/Circle Details</th>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Locations
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
                <td>
                  {{dashboard.locations}}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Registered BC/Agents
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
                <td>
                  {{dashboard.registeredbc}}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  Active BC/Agents
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
                <td>
                  {{dashboard.activebc}}
                </td>
              </tr>

            </table>
          </td>

          <td style=" text-align: left; padding: 8px; ">
            <table style="background-color: white;width:100%;">
              <th style="  background-color: #81A594;color: white;">Today`s Analysis</th>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="reportsnew.do?method=reports&rname=Enrollments&date=crr">Enrollments</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
                <td>
                  {{dashboard.enrollments}}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="reportsnew.do?method=reports&rname=AccountOpened&date=crr">Accounts Opened</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
                <td>
                  {{dashboard.accopened}}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="reportsnew.do?method=reports&rname=VerificationPending&date=crr">Verification Pending(Total)</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
                <td>
                  {{dashboard.verpending}}
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr>
                <td>
                  <a href="reportsnew.do?method=reports&rname=RejectedEnrollments&date=crr">Rejected Enrollments</a>
                </td>
              </tr>
              <tr style="background-color: #f2f2f2;">
                <td>
                  {{dashboard.rejected}}
                </td>
              </tr>
            </table>
          </td>


        </tr>
      </table>
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you mean when you say 'angular.min.js' is not being loaded. I copied your code to my local machine - commented-out the ajax call to getdashboarddata() since I do not have access to your server - then ran the page in Chrome:

- looking at Chrome's DevTools, under the networking tab, do you see the call to the ajax.googleapis.com server? Does it get a response?
- are any errors appearing in Chromes DevTools console?

When I ran your page locally, I do get the alert message you define in your Controller which tells me that Angular is loading and running. The alert message itself says 'undefined Angular' because Obj1 is not defined in the scope of the controller.